# What is different between Toast lengthLong and lengthShort?

Tags: android, toast

I have been searching from internet and trying on my application. I cant found what is the different between `LENGTH_LONG` and `LENGTH_SHORT`. So what is the different between both of them and when to use them.

Comment: They just determine how long to display the `Toast`. `LENGTH_LONG` is 3.5 seconds, and `LENGTH_SHORT` is 2 seconds. Use as you see appropriate.

Comment: Duration. `Length long` is 3.5 second however `short` is 2 second. Toast is one of the I consider Pop up message, other pop up message can consider `AlertBuilder`. useful too

Answer (score 2):

Both are used for duration of `Toast` visible

**LENGTH_LONG**  syntax

private static final int **LONG_DELAY** = 3500; // 3.5 seconds

**LENGTH_SHORT**  syntax

private static final int **SHORT_DELAY** = 2000; // 2 seconds

Comment: the only different is the time duration only ?

Comment: yes.. only duration for displaying toast message